# A new menu seen in Salesforce classic. What is this?

Tags: salesforce-classic, menu

I see a new menu in salesforce [image]

`__MISSING LABEL__ PropertyFile - val InteractionObjectStateDefinition not found in section Setup_NavNew!`

What is this?
When I expand and click to see its fields it throws error:

```
Insufficient Privileges
```

> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation
> you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your
> administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see
> Insufficient Privileges Errors.
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

Comment: Looks like a bug from SF side, I'd rather log a case with support regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documented known issue

[Error in Classic setup of Winter'22 orgs : **MISSING LABEL** PropertyFile - val InteractionObjectStateDefinition not found in section Setup_Nav](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000028vFJQAY)

There's no workaround, but it shouldn't have any functionality impacts as there's no related feature to that object (and it's only in Classic UI)